# avconv / ffmpeg covert images to video skips frames when frame type changes

Tags: video, ffmpeg, libav, image-processing

I have an instance of ffmpeg that captures one fps from our home CCTV cameras. At the end of the day I have an ffmpeg script that takes those images and turns them into a video. This is fine with one of our home cameras however one camera seems to change the frame type when the camera changes to a IR mode. Images are still captured, but when attempting to covert the images to a video at the end of the day thousands of frames are skipped preceded by this message:

> frame changed from size:960x720 fmt:gray to size:960x720  fmt:yuvj420p

I've tried this with avconv and ffmpeg and haven't been able to solve this issue.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The complete console output from your `ffmpeg` command would provide some useful info.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jLLYKJtd